# file_unmanaged_copy - Any service alternatives?

Tags: 8, files

The functionality of the `file_unmanaged_copy` is exactly what I need. The only problem is: it's a global function which uses static service calls.
Since I need to unit test my class (and not to mention how I dislike hidden dependencies coming from global functions) I can't use it.

Am working with D8 since the very beginning, but am failed to find any OO alternatives. Has anyone faced the same situation? Any "Best-practises" or workarounds?

Comment: There is no oop replacement yet. There are a number of issues to convert those function to services but it didn't happen yet. The common approach that core uses to solve this problem so to hide this function in a protected method and in the unit test, you mock your own class so that you are able to mock that method. Or you make a separate service that just wraps that method so you can mock it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This changed in Drupal 8.7.0
See https://www.drupal.org/node/3006851

```php
try {
  \Drupal::service('file_system')->copy($source, $destination, $replace);
} 
catch (\Drupal\Core\File\Exception\FileException $e) {
    // Log or set message or doing something else.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for now **Berdir**'s comment is the right answer:

> There is no oop replacement yet. There are a number of issues to
>   convert those function to services but it didn't happen yet. The
>   common approach that core uses to solve this problem so to hide this
>   function in a protected method and in the unit test, you mock your own
>   class so that you are able to mock that method. Or you make a separate
>   service that just wraps that method so you can mock it

Personally, I prefer the later one, wrapping it the globals into a service.